# ASP.NET TemplateField Editable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I added a dropdown box to my GridView as follows

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upgrade">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUpgrade" runat="server" Width="100px">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="5">6</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

All other columns aren't editable to start which is what I want but adding the dropdown box makes it editable when it shouldn't be. It should only become editable when I click the controls edit button

What might the trick be here?

**UPDATE**

Karl Anderson post did the trick.

This did the trick but now when I try to update that row, in the OnUpdating event wherne I assign those parameters to grab the values from the dropdownlist, they are always reflecting the fist item. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the drop down list in the `<EditItemTemplate>` instead of the `<ItemTemplate>` and put a `Label` control in the `<ItemTemplate>`, like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upgrade">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelUpgrade" runat="server" 
                   Text='<%# Eval("Upgrade") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUpgrade" runat="server" Width="100px">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="5">6</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now when you first view the grid it will show the label and only show the drop down list when it is in "edit mode".

Comment: This did the trick but now when I try to update that row, in the OnUpdating event wherne I assign those parameters to grab the values from the dropdownlist, they are always reflecting the fist item. Any idea?

Comment: @Tsukasa - my guess is that the drop down list is being reset to the first item after posting back to the server. I would recommend starting a new question exclusively about this new issue.

Comment: ok the actual issue is that it's not letting me reference ddlUpgrade in the CodeBehind

Comment: @Tsukasa - I would start a new question with the code-behind that does not allow you to reference the `ddlUpgrade` control. This will cause less confusion than an add-on question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly , you are going to want to add an EditItemTemplate to each Template field. So if you have labels in the other TemplateFields, it should look something similar to this..

**ASP**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False">
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="tbTextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FromDatabase")%>'></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblALabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FromDatabase") %>'</asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But if you want everything to be editable from the get go, then you should have textboxs within the ItemTemplate fields. Then to make them editable on the "edit" click, click the smart tag, edit columns, then add CommandField. The Command field already has Cancel, Delete, Edit and so on. Once you add that, you should be able to click edit, everything that has an editfield will now show. Hope this helps!